# Relationship among $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$ to have a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

If $b= \begin{bmatrix}
        b_1 \\
         b_2\\
         b_3\\
        \end{bmatrix}$, what relationship(s) must hold among $b_1, b_2, b_3$ in order for there to be a solution?

I began this problem by doing Gaussian Elimination on an augmented matrix. This is my result:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 2 & 3 & b_1 \\
        0 & -3 & -6 & b_2 - 4b_1\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & b_3 - 7 b_1 - 2 b_2\\
        \end{array}\right]$

Is this correct, and where do I go from here?

Comment: So $b_3-7b_1-2b_2=0$. Since $0+0+0$ has to be $0$.

Comment: When you turn a matrix to REF, any row that ends up 0 has to have 0 in the corresponding (transformed) vector component in order for a solution to be possible.  Thus you get Fan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the existence of a solution, the system of equations must be consistent. In this case, a solution exists when $$b_3 - 7b_1 - 2b_2 = 0.$$ Any value other than $0$ on the right-hand side would yield an inconsistent system (no solution exists, period), since the last row represents the equation $0x + 0y + 0z = b_3 - 7b_1 - 2b_2 = c$, and *unless* $c =0$, no solution exists.

In this case, with $c=0$, we are not only guaranteed that a solution exists, but it turns out that infinitely many solutions exist, because $z$ can take on any real value $t$, and for each and every such value $t$, there corresponds a solution with $x$ and $ y$ functions of $t$.

Comment: I thought that I would have to do something like this:


Solve for any b (lets say $b_1$), then do 

b = $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2b_2-b_3 \\
        ? \\
        ? \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$.


I just don't know what I would put for $b_2$ and $b_3$. I know one would be the free variable, but I don't know what to do with the other variable.

Comment: You don't have to solve for $b_1, b_2, b_3$ (there's not enough information to do so). The question asks what the relationship among them is, and what we can say is given by the equation posted above.

Comment: Okay. That makes more sense. Thank you for your help!